# Bing not showing search results for simple search with Puppeteer. Same URL works in Chrome

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I've previously been getting results from bing using Puppeteer, but I'm now receiving the below error.

[image]

This comes from the following code, which previously worked.

```
(async () => {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.bing.com/search?q=example+searchterm", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})

})();
```

When I do the same search in my browser, I get thousands of pages of results. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Have you found any workaround? We are stuck with that thing too.